# React Component's performance reduce when rendering a large list using array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
<div className="listCheckbox">
            {objects.map((e) => {
              return (
                <div key={e.value}>
                  <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label={e.label} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>

//css----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.listCheckbox {
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

here objects are a state of type array and contain more than 250 records. how can I render this more efficiently with the same styling

Answer (score 2):

You can use pagination and limit the records instead of showing it all. And when you try to render more you can just add it to the `previous state`, This way you won't lose your `previous fetched records` and it will be more optimized.

Comment: is there any other solution other than pagination???

Comment: There is one other way.  As you know  `react` takes time when trying to `render` for the first time. So what you can do is the first time website loads you can `fetch` the data in `useEffect` and store it in the `state` and then you can `render` it whenever you want and it won't take much time because it is already in your `state`.

Comment: that's what i m doing but still getting issues

Comment: You can implement `infinite scroll` in your component. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to load large list of data:

Note: I have mentioned some npm libraries within brackets for ease, but these functionalities can be self-implemented as well.

1. pagination (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate)
2. inifinite scroll (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)

Also check [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/4-ways-to-render-large-lists-in-react/) blog for more options and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not interested in paginating, you should use a virtual list.

You can use [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), or try building [one from scratch](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/building-a-virtualized-list-from-scratch-9225e8bec120)