# How can I optimize the performance of a React application that's rendering a large list of items?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React application that needs to display a large list of items (thousands of rows). Currently, the performance is quite slow when the user is scrolling through the list or filtering the items. What are some ways that I can optimize the performance of my React application to improve the user experience?

Some additional information:

-I'm using React functional components and hooks to render the list of items.
-Each item in the list contains several fields of data, including text and images.

-I'm currently using the built-in map function to render the list of items.

-I'm using a library to handle filtering and sorting the list of items.

-I've already tried implementing shouldComponentUpdate and React.memo to improve performance, but it's still not fast enough.

I'm open to any suggestions, including using third-party libraries or rewriting parts of the application if necessary. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would help if you provided code samples or a reproducible sandbox for the component that's having the issue.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478277/react-components-performance-reduce-when-rendering-a-large-list-using-array Basically answers you can get here would be almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the library [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window). It's useful to virtualize the scroll in a large list of elements and should help you in performance tuning.